# database scheme for shops schedule

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, laravel-5

I need an advise how to build scheme for shops schedule.
For example shops can have working days from monday to friday (from 09-00 to 18-00) with saturday and sunday off.
It's easy can be done like this:
shop_id    day_of_week    from_time   to_time

But shops can also work by odd/even days of month, and no matter if it's odd/even they have sunday off.
How to build such type of scheme ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is:
`shop_id`,`sunday_open_time`, `sunday_close_time`...`saturday_open_time`,`saturday_close_time`(set both open and close time for day to zero if not open that day), `is_open_odd_days_only`(boolean), `is_open_even_days_only`(boolean).